# Why does my dog whine on walks?

Tags: dogs, psychology, leash-training

Why does my dog whine while we go on walks?  We walk almost everyday. As soon as we get the leash she starts whining and whines almost the whole walk.  She will walk by my side and it's like she's looking up at me whining like she wants something from me.  It seems very anxious.  She is kind of a fraidy cat dog.  She LOVES the walks and doesn't whine like this at any other time. We walk about four miles a day.

Comment: How do you know she loves the walks, if the only time she whines is when she is walling?

Comment: would it be better to put it as why does my dog whine when we go on walks?